# Detecting the geometry of irregular regions in an image in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have a 2D image that has been produced as the result of applying k-means clustering to an original image. The clustering was applied to detect different color regions in the original image. Here is one example of the resulting clusters,

[image]

The colored region (purple) is the shape of the cluster in original the 2D image. I want to be able to detect (and store) the shape of this cluster and apply it to another picture. To elaborate more, after capturing this shape I want to draw (or construct) a region with a similar shape in another image and apply the same color to it.

I have searched for this detecting ability in MATLAB, but most of the algorithms I found detect regular shapes like squares, and circles. I tried to use active activecontour as suggested by the answer here, [Random object detection matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284678/random-object-detection-matlab). Based on the **first** code provided at MATLAB website here, http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/activecontour.html, I've written this code,

```
I = imread('clusterimg.png');
imshow(I)
title('Original Image');

mask = zeros(size(I));
mask(25:end-25,25:end-25) = 1;
  
figure, imshow(mask);
title('Initial Contour Location');

bw = activecontour(I,mask,300);
  
figure, imshow(bw);
title('Segmented Image');
```

But, when I run it I get this error,

```
Undefined function 'activecontour' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.
Error in geometrydetection (line 11)
bw = activecontour(I,mask,300);
```

What I need to know is the following,

1- What mistake I did in the code above?

2- Is `activecontour` a good way to achieve the geometry detection I described above? If yes, after detecting the geometry of a region, how can I construct a similar one in another image? If no, can you please provided an alternative method that can detect the geometry of a region, and construct a similar one in another image?

EDIT: The suggestion of using `bwconncomp` by **mvai** may be good. I've found this example (available here, http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/labeling-and-measuring-objects-in-a-binary-image.html),

```
cc = bwconncomp(BW)
cc = 

    Connectivity: 8
       ImageSize: [8 9]
      NumObjects: 3
    PixelIdxList: {[6x1 double]  [6x1 double]  [5x1 double]}
```

Can anyone please tell me if there is a way to know the distance that separates every component from the another one?

Thank You.

Comment: Check for `bwconncomp`.

Comment: What do you mean by applying the same shape to a different image? If you would like to use the purple region as a mask you could use logical indexing. If not, have you had a look at edge()?http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/edge.html?refresh=true

Comment: @mvai thank you, this seems good. Can you please tell me what is the principle that this function uses to find connected regions? I read the documentation, it seems that there is a neighboring principle, but it is not clear, what is meant by 8 and 26 neighbors? How can that help? Thanks.

Comment: @lhcgeneva, I mean that I want to construct an identical region in the new image similar to the one that was detected in the original one. I don't think edge will solve that, I will check for logical indexing. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`bwconncomp`](http://it.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwconncomp.html) might help. It looks for connected components in a binary image.

```
CC = bwconncomp(I,connectivity);
```

From `CC` you can get the number of regions and their indexes, see the documentation for help.

The connectivity parameter, for 2D images, is basically a 3x3 matrix of 0s and 1s. It represents the neighborhood locations in respect to the central pixel. If you use the scalar value `4`, the resulting matrix will be:

```
0  1  0
1  1  1
0  1  0
```

while `8` is:

```
1  1  1
1  1  1
1  1  1
```

Since your regions don't have particular shapes, I believe the default (`8`) is ok for you.

Comment: @mavi, thanks a lot, by central pixel do you mean the pixel in the 2nd row and second column? Is it always set to 1? Also, I have some questions regarding the distance that separate components form each other, I've posted that as an update in the question. Can you please tell me if there is a way to check for the separating distance? Thank you.

Comment: It depends on your definition of distance. A good starting point might be `L = labelmatrix(CC)`, and using `regionprops` on L. `regionprops` (look at the docs) can return lots of spatial properties for each region, like its centroid. You could then calculate the distance between each centroid.

Comment: Central value in the matrix has to be 1 and it is the pixel currently investigated by `bwconncomp`. I don't know how it works internally, but basically it moves over the image, centering on a pixel and looking for connected values in neighbor pixels. Which neighbor pixels to investigate, is what you decide with the connectivity matrix.

Comment: I've converted the image to gray scale then to binary image, I've ran bwconncomp, but I got weird results like this, PixelIdxList: {1x44 cell}, what does this mean? I've read the docs, but the examples I've seen are of another form (eg, [6x1 double] which means 6 pixels in this connected component). Does it mean that we have one region with 44 pixels? Also, when I print labelmatrix, I get a very big matrix with different row lengths, is this normal? Please help me understand this. Thanks.

Comment: You have 44 regions, CC.PixelIdxList(k) are the pixels of the k-th, cell2mat(CC.PixelIdxList(k)) is the same in a matrix form (-> an array).

Comment: thanks a lot I got it. I would really appreciate it if you help me answer this last question, what does the value for each pixel in the array generate by cell2mat(CC.PixelIdxList(k)) mean (eg, color or intensity)?

Comment: It is the position in the original image, in form of linear indices.